# Python Palindrome swapper

Tags: string, python-3.x, palindrome

I'm trying to write a palindrome swapper function which takes a string:

If a palindrome can be created by swapping two adjacent characters in the string it should return the palindrome (for eg. for input string "kyaak", if we swap characters in indices 1 and 2, "kayak" is formed which is a palindrome)  else it should return the string -1. What's wrong here?

```
def PalindromeSwapper(s): 
    for idx,i in enumerate(s[:]):
        if (s[idx],s[idx+1]  == s[idx+1],s[idx]) and (s[:] == s[::-1]):
            return s[:]
        else:
            return -1
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93225/checking-if-any-permutation-of-a-string-can-make-it-palindrome

Comment: Try printing the values of `s[idx],s[idx+1])` and `(s[idx+1],s[idx])` and ask when those pair would be equal. That's what you are testing for. And then do the same for `(s[:]` and  `s[::-1])` This function will return true for a string like "yyaayy"

Answer (score 0):

This code is working now:

```
def PalindromeSwapper(s):
    length = len(s)
    for idx, i in enumerate(s):
        if idx == length-1: return -1  # if idx==length-1, then t[idx+1] will give IndexError
        t = list(s)  # make list, so swapping is possible
        t[idx], t[idx+1]  = t[idx+1], t[idx]  # swap characters
        t = ''.join(c for c in t)  # rebuild string from list
        if t == t[::-1]: return t  # palindrome condition
```

There were actually a few mistakes in your code. The first one was `s[idx],s[idx+1]  == s[idx+1],s[idx]` as @Mark_M already stated in the comment. The second one was putting the `return -1` where you put it because this way `-1` is returned right after the first iteration of the for-loop (i.e. when `idx` is `0`, what happens with larger values of `idx` isn't even checked).
I hope you understand how the code presented here takes care of these mistakes.

As the two following examples show, it can be useful to feed `s` and `s[::-1]` into the function to get the palindrome that makes sense (depending on where the original swap of two characters took place):

```
>>> PalindromeSwapper('kayka')  # swaps the first two characters and finds palindrome
'akyka'
>>> PalindromeSwapper('kayka'[::-1])
'kayak'
```